# Upload image from iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm confused with uploading an image from iPhone, I don't know if I choose to to use  `base64encoding` or `multi-part` data.

Comment: Depends on the server where you upload the image. What does the server expects? You can [edit] your question to add more information and details about your issue.

Comment: I will save it to my cpanel file manager,

Comment: You theoretically could upload using ftp, but it's probably easier to write your own web service to upload. And when you write your own web service, you can implement that any way you want, but `multi-part/formdata` is probably easiest (esp if you use a library like Alamofire to get you out of the weeds of constructing your own `multi-part/formdata` request.

Comment: Thanks people, I will try to use the base64encoding for this ios app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to upload the base64 string on server so that you extract and get real image from the string on server.

otherwise both way is available to uploading image on server.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to using base64encoding for my mobile app.

Comment: is there any help needed let me know.

Comment: Thanks @Hemanth , I encoded the image but when the encode string pass to server all the "+" sign replaced by whitespace

Comment: @johnyald - When you do a standard HTTP `POST`, the `+` is replaced with a space. You have to percent-escape it if you are doing a `POST`

Comment: thankyou @Rob, is it normal? the image captured by iphone taking too long to encode.

Comment: @johnyald - Encoding is generally very quick. You should post a new question, showing us what you've done, and we can diagnose what's going on.

Comment: let theImg = imageview.image!  
let imgrep = UIImagePNGRepresentation(theImg)
let b64 = imgrep!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

Answer (score 0):

let theImg = imageview.image!
let imgrep = UIImagePNGRepresentation(theImg)

let b64 = imgrep!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

Comment: OK, that will encode it and it should go very quickly. What is the problem. You suggest that it's "taking too long to encode". How have you concluded that?

Comment: When I encode image from the simulator it takes 3mins using "UIImagePNGRepresentation" but now I used "let imgrep = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(theImg, 0.5)" and it works fine sir.

Comment: Just for a coule of seconds.

Comment: @Rob - thankyou sir I appreciate your perseverance for answering my questions

Comment: Compare the `length` of the PNG representation vs. the JPEG representation. The former will be larger, most likely, but I have a hard time imagining that it would take three minutes.

Comment: PNG representation has the larger size, and when I decode it the image file double up,

Comment: Yes, you'd expect that. But the encoding process should go from something like 100ms to 200ms, not from milliseconds to minutes. I personally suspect that this "3 minute" issue is something completely unrelated. But, in the absence of a reproducible example of your three minute delay, it's hard to say much other than that.

Comment: thanks rob, I think it will be okay for now. I used to change the "+" sign also to "%2b" when passing to my server to decode it back to image. Do you think it will be fine for the app? that kind of uploading an image.

Comment: I cannot comment on your implementation without seeing it. But if you have an implementation that is working and you're requesting a design/code review, you'd generally post that to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

let theImg = imageview.image!
let imgrep = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(theImg, 0.5)
let b64 = imgrep!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

let replaced = b64.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+", withString: "%2b")

Comment: @Rob - this what i've done. Im sending the 'replaced' string to my site to convert all "%2b" to "+", what do you think?

Comment: Why need to replaced + with symbols for parsing. you can directly user string methods for html parsing strings.

Comment: @HemanthShah how that will work? Can you give me some codes for that. I appreciate you effort

Comment: var escapedAddress = address.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())

Comment: @HemanthShah thankyou, but still the plus sign become whitespace when pass to the server and make it as data